# elementary OS takes up to 20 seconds to login after I enter my login password

Tags: release-loki

I am using elmentaryOS Loki.
It takes up to 20 seconds to show desktop after I enter my password.
Please help me out.
**Update**: I have update my Linux Kernel to 4.10 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rename the file: /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop
to /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled

Comment: I have update my Linux Kernel to 4.10 version. is kernel update causing this problem?

Comment: Btw, renaming that file did help. wouldn't disabling `at-spi-dbus-bus` create any problem in desktop?

Comment: I have yet to have a problem after I disabled it. So I am going to say no.

For others who want a command to copy and past to perform this, 

>sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled